# Unable to npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, sass

I just want to get this React app going?? using -> npm run dev

Error:

```
npm run dev  

> letters-social@1.0.0 dev
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm-run-all -p api client:dev server:dev styles:w


> letters-social@1.0.0 styles:w
> npm run styles && node-sass src/styles/styles.scss -o static/ -w src/styles --watch --recursive


> letters-social@1.0.0 client:dev
> webpack-dev-server --config ./build/webpack.config.js


> letters-social@1.0.0 server:dev
> nodemon --config nodemon.json index.js


> letters-social@1.0.0 api
> nodemon -x node -r @std/esm ./db/run.js

[nodemon] 1.12.5
[nodemon] 1.12.5
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node -r @std/esm ./db/run.js`

> letters-social@1.0.0 styles
> node-sass -q src/styles/styles.scss -o static/

node[42883]: ../src/node_file.cc:1038:void node::fs::Stat(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `(argc) == (4)' failed.
 1: 0x102422a25 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x1011180f9 node::Abort() [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x101117f31 node::Assert(node::AssertionInfo const&) [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
 4: 0x101126bb4 node::fs::Stat(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
 5: 0x1013021b9 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo) [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x101301c86 v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x1013013ff v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
 8: 0x101b748f9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_BuiltinExit [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
 9: 0x101b072ea Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/Users/Zouhir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.14.0/bin/node]
10: 0x107d9f204 
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
/Users/Zouhir/Documents/REACT/letters-social/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13
      throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
      ^

Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
    at module.exports (/Users/Zouhir/Documents/REACT/letters-social/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
```

package.json

```
...
   "scripts": {
        "analyze": "cross-env ANALYZE=true npm run build",
        "api": "nodemon -x node -r @std/esm ./db/run.js",
        "build:app": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress --config ./build/webpack.config.prod.js",
        "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm-run-all build:app db:seed",
        "client:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./build/webpack.config.js",
        "doc": "esdoc -c esdoc.json",
        "db:seed": "node -r @std/esm db/seed.js",
        "deploy": "now -e LETTERS_FIREBASE_ADMIN_KEY=${LETTERS_FIREBASE_ADMIN_KEY} -d",
        "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npm-run-all -p api client:dev server:dev styles:w",
        "server:dev": "nodemon --config nodemon.json index.js",
        "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production pm2 start ./index.js --no-daemon",
        "styles:w": "npm run styles && node-sass src/styles/styles.scss -o static/ -w src/styles --watch --recursive",
        "styles": "node-sass -q src/styles/styles.scss -o static/",
        "test:w": "jest --watch --coverage",
        "test": "jest --coverage"
    },
...
 "dependencies": {
        ...
        "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
```

node version: 
v16.14.0 
npm version: 
8.3.1

I tried all these node versions: 
v8.0.0
v8.17.0
v10.24.1
v11.0.0
v14.15.0 
->     v16.14.0 
v17.7.0 
 
and also different node-sass package version also 
4.7.2
... (forgot)

also tried 
 npm rebuild node-sass (something like that can't remember) 
 
directory: [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv3v2.png)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

1. install / downgrade node.js to a stable version (LTS) like 14.15.0
2. install the compatible node-sass version via npm install
   node-sass@4.14.0; you can find the list [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass), or even install
   gulp-sasswith npm i gulp-sass --save-dev.